# Convert groovy Closure to Java?

Tags: java, rest, groovy

*EDIT: Why the down-votes? Been googling this at length, without success...*

I have some groovy-classes, I'm trying to rewrite to Java.

The groovy-code uses wslite for REST-calls, and follows this pattern:

```
JsonBuilder request = createRequest();
Map<String, Object> params = createParams();
RESTClient client = new RESTClient(endpoint);
Response response = client.put(params) ( it -> { text(request); });
```

How do I rewrite the final line with the Closure part?

What is the Java equivalent?

Comment: Why the down-votes? Been googling this at length, without success...

Comment: Rewriting just closure to java is possible, but has no sense because of complexity in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't understand the goal because it's better to change rest-client if you are switching to java.

wslite library designed for groovy and using it for java will add complexity to your code.

---

However, in this particular case java code will look like this:

(it's groovy but with java-like syntax)

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.2', transitive=false)

import groovy.json.*
import wslite.rest.*

@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class TextBodyClosure extends Closure<Object> {
    Object body;
    public TextBodyClosure(Object owner, Object body) {
        super(owner);
        this.body = body;
    }
    public Object call() {
        ContentBuilder cb = (ContentBuilder)this.getDelegate();
        cb.text(body);
        return null;
    }
}

def content = ["hello": "world"];
JsonBuilder request = new JsonBuilder(content);
Map<String, Object> params = [:];
RESTClient client = new RESTClient("http://httpbin.org/put");
//Response response = client.put(params){ it -> text(request) };
Response response = client.put(params, new TextBodyClosure(this, request));

assert response.parsedResponseContent.json.json == content
println "SUCCESS"
```

this conversion based on a source code of wslite library.

when you are calling `client.put(params, content)` the following code executed to transform content-closure to bytes:

https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite/blob/master/src/main/groovy/wslite/rest/RESTClient.groovy#L101-L105

[image]

as you can see - the content-closure passed into ContentBuilder that executes closure against itself - so, the delegate object is ContentBuilder at moment of execution...

https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite/blob/master/src/main/groovy/wslite/rest/ContentBuilder.groovy#L45

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So `Closure` is just an object in Java.  You would just need to create an anonymous class that extends Closure.

```
client.put( new Closure<Integer>(null) { //need to pass owner = null
    @Override
    public Integer call() {
       return 100;
    }
});
```

This of course requires you have groovy libraries in your classpath, but you'd have to do that anyway to support using ws-lite since it would require Groovy.  Something to consider is that you have to have Groovy in your classpath to use ws-lite so unless you are stripping that out too why not just use Groovy to do your script?  You're not saving yourself any performance by writing the wrapper in Java if Java just calls ws-lite to do the bulk of the work.

Comment: hmm... but where does that text() method come from? It's not defined in our code that I can see... how does groovy evaluate that?

Comment: text is defined here https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite/blob/4457c93354f6c20b1c32b689469ef5794037db8b/src/main/groovy/wslite/rest/ContentBuilder.groovy#L73